# Systemverilog: scope of text substitution macro

Tags: system-verilog

I read that text substitution macros have global scope in 'verilog'. How does SystemVerilog work? I want to use 2 different definitions of the same text macro in 2 different SystemVerilog files - is that OK to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SystemVerilog, macro definitions are limited to the compilation-unit scope but what that is depends on the tool configuration. From the specification:

> The exact mechanism for defining which files constitute a compilation
>   unit is tool-specific. However, compliant tools shall provide use
>   models that allow both of the following cases:
>
> a) All files on a given compilation command line make a single
>       compilation unit (in which case the declarations within those files
>       are accessible following normal visibility rules throughout the
>       entire set of files).
>
> b) Each file is a separate compilation unit (in which case the
>       declarations in each compilation-unit scope are accessible only
>       within its corresponding file).

Therefore if you use multiple-file compilation units (`-mfcu` for Modelsim), there will be collisions since the macro namespace will have global scope. However the specification explicitly allows redefinitions so you may not get an error(or warning) in this case, unless your tool supports it.

> The text macro name space is global within the compilation unit.
>   Because text macro names are introduced and used with a leading ‘
>   character, they remain unambiguous with any other name space. The text
>   macro names are defined in the linear order of appearance in the set
>   of input files that make up the compilation unit. Subsequent
>   definitions of the same name override the previous definitions for the
>   balance of the input files.

Depending on how you are using macros, you may want to consider using parameters instead. Parameters are essentially constants that are more limited in scope than preprocessor directives. They can also be used to selectively instance code using generate constructs.

You can get the SV specification [here](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf) for free.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. I think the selectively instanced code using the parameter/generate approach needs to be syntactically complete to avoid a compilation error. But with text macros, it can be a fragment that will only compile when used in the proper context. That's the capability I need.

Answer (score 1):

If the desired macro have simuliar structure/format, then you can use macro with arguments. See IEEE1800-2012 Section 22.5.1.

```
`define myMacro(arg1,arg2) \
    prefix_``arg1 = arg2``_postfix
```

If the desired macro definition is exclusively in its respected file and unique, then you can do the following. All other files will not have an `` `mymacro `` that can be called. `` `undef `` is from Verilog, IEEE1364-1995 Section 16.3.2, and has been in included into SystemVerilog. You can read more about `` `undef `` in the latest revision; IEEE1800-2012 Section 22.5.2.

file1.sv:

```
`define mymacro abcd
/* SystemVerilog code */
`undef mymacro
```

file2.sv:

```
`define mymacro wxyz
/* SystemVerilog code */
`undef mymacro
```